# What Should I Learn First?

Tags: html, web-applications, formatting

I have just scratched the surface in the world of programming, and I need to know where to begin. I work for a Web-page writing articles, and I face a raise if I learn to format the article myself. I want to learn how to format, and also how to code. Is there anywhere in particular where I should begin my journey to programming things such as web-applications?

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna W3Schools is a pretty bad website with questionable content. Several experts teamed up against it, please see http://w3fools.com/ . (Personally I'm not against it on that level, I'm just saying that some of the W3Schools content is most likely crap and you have to seek better references as a beginner - it doesn't take much to find better stuff out there.)

Comment: But to my personal experience it was good for basic level. And Thank's for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are just a hint. This journey is quite long and after a basic level, you have a multitude of options...

- First of all: **learn HTML**. There's nothing to do if you cannot understand the content you're creating.
- **Learn CSS** - this will help you to achieve the formatting in the right way and will make you understand how web pages are styled. *That's where the fun begins, with knowing some CSS you will be able to make a web site look good.*
- **Get a decent code editor** for working, prototyping. If you really want to understand what's going on, then prefer non-WYSIWYG editors (you will see what I mean). *The more decent you can get the better - this will help you in your daily work, better to not choose one which is irritating for you.* (Personally I use PhpStorm which is a really good, professional tool. It might be too advanced for beginners.)
- All web pages nowadays are created dynamically, for example via PHP. **Learning to code in PHP** will make you busy for quite a bit of time, so it would be the best to get a good book about it. (This will also start you up learning about databases, where the actual information is stored.) *In my opinion, this is where the real part of web programming begins.*
- After writing some basic stuff with PHP, **get familiar with different frameworks/CMSs** just to know how we deal with big, real sites. (WordPress is great for starting and it's advanced enough to use it on a real site.) There's no point in reinventing the wheel, so always try to have a look whether others have done what you would like to do before. *There's always a toolkit for the common tasks.*

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's been rough finding where to start.